# Active Element On Load

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have some elements taking advantage of some Bootstrap 4 features as well as some custom settings.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-selector make-active">
        <input type="radio" name="options">A
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-selector">
        <input type="radio" name="options">B
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-selector">
        <input type="radio" name="options">C
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-selector">
        <input type="radio" name="options">D
    </label>
</div>
```

For this group I would like one of the `labels` to be active when the page loads. If I give the desired element the `active` class it is set on page load but is quickly removed by the browser.

I have attempted setting the class using the following but it inst always effective (sometimes page loads without setting class).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('label.make-active').addClass('active');
});
```

How can I make sure an active element keeps its active status on page load?

Ideally I could set this active status on the server.

Edit: Looks like Bootstrap may be to blame here

```
          if (activeElement) {
            $(activeElement).removeClass(CLASS_NAME_ACTIVE);
          }
```

Comment: Setting the `.active` class on the label should work. Seems like you might have other code that is changing it

Comment: @abney317 I think you may be right, removing this file leaves them active `bootstrap.bundle.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in `bootstrap.bundle.js` requires that our `input` of type `radio` also be checked to prevent the `active` class from being removed.

```
      if (input.type === 'radio') {
        if (input.checked && this._element.classList.contains(CLASS_NAME_ACTIVE)) {
          triggerChangeEvent = false;
        } else {
          var activeElement = rootElement.querySelector(SELECTOR_ACTIVE);

          if (activeElement) {
            $(activeElement).removeClass(CLASS_NAME_ACTIVE);
          }
        }
      }
```